# Failed to register classes with Kryo

Tags: clojure, kryo, flambo

I am creating a spark context by using-

```
(ns something
  (:require [flambo.conf : conf]
                 [flambo.api :as f]))
(def c (-> (conf/spark-conf)
           (conf/master "spark://formcept008.lan:7077") 
           (conf/app-name "clustering")))  ;; app-name   
(def sc (f/spark-context c))
```

Then I am creating an RDD-

```
(f/parallelize sc DATA)
```

Now when I am performing some action on this data, like (f/take rdd 3) etc, I am getting an error-

> 17/11/28 14:35:00 ERROR Utils: Exception encountered
>       org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:129)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.borrowKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:274)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.(KryoSerializer.scala:259)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newInstance(KryoSerializer.scala:175)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:79)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1273)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:253)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: flambo.kryo.BaseFlamboRegistrator
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anonfun$newKryo$5.apply(KryoSerializer.scala:124)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anonfun$newKryo$5.apply(KryoSerializer.scala:124)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>           at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:124)
>           ... 27 more
>       17/11/28 14:35:00 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2449)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1385)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:253)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Any thoughts on that, please.

Comment: Please create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this issue

Comment: This is already a small code. The issue is when i am performing an action on rdd, spark is not able to complete the job, because of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Add all the jars of your project in spark-configuration by using -

```
(conf/jars (map #(.getPath % (.getURLs(java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader))))
```

It will register all the classes.
Since this issue is resolved, so closing it.

Comment: hi - I am new to databricks. Can you please clearly state where to add these jar files or how to add this configuration. I know Python & familiar with Spark but not Java. I figured out that there is an option to upload jars by creating library under workspace but not sure where to put the command you show above?

Answer (score 0):

flambo doesn't seem to be in your classpath somehow which is why you're getting:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: flambo.kryo.BaseFlamboRegistrator`

Are you running this from the REPL or are you using a lein or boot task?

if you're using leiningen check your classpath (`lein classpath`) and dependency tree (`lein deps :tree`)

*Also, it never hurts to do a `lein clean` to make sure your target folder isn't causing issues*

**Stack trace analysis:**
The `Failed to register classes with Kryo` is caused because `flambo.kryo.BaseFlamboRegistrator` is missing

Comment: Hi Gary,
Flambo exists in my classpath, I have checked. And I am running it using lein run as all the namespaces are aot compiled. I did lein clean also and checked the dependency tree. Flambo exists at both the places, classpath as well as dependency. 
Any other suggestion.